# Expected value of $S_{xx}$ for simple linear regression

Tags: regression

I've been trying to figure out the expected value of $S_{xx}$. This is where I am at currently:
\begin{align*}
E\left[ S_{xx} \right] &= E\left[ \left( x_i - \overline{x} \right)^2 \right]\\
&= E\left[ x_i^2 - \overline{x} x_i \right]\\
&= E\left[ x_i^2 \right] - E\left[ \overline{x} x_i \right]\\
&= Var\left[ x_i \right] + E\left[ x_i \right]^2 - E \left[\overline{x} x_i \right]\\
&= Var\left[ x_i \right] + E\left[ x_i \right]^2 - \overline{x} E \left[x_i \right]\\
&= Var\left[ x_i \right] + \overline{x}^2 - \overline{x}^2\\
&= Var\left[ x_i \right]\\
&= E\left[ \left( x_i - \overline{x} \right)^2 \right]
\end{align*}

Comment: In the usual linear regression model, $x$ is treated as a constant, not as a random variable!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks! So that means $E \left[ S_{xx} \right] = S_{xx}$ right? Since $E \left[ x_i^2 \right] - E \left[ \overline{x}x_i \right] = x_i^2 - \overline{x} x_i = x_i \left( x_i - \overline{x} \right) = S_{xx}$

Comment: The expectation of any constant, such as $S_{xx},$ equals that constant.  This follows directly from the definition of expectation.

Comment: @whuber Got it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The predictor $x_i$ are assumed to be fixed, not random. They are fixed in the sense that they are taken to be known values. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
E\left[ S_{xx} \right] &= E\left[ \sum \left( x_i - \overline{x} \right)^2 \right]\\
&= E\left[ \sum \left( x_i^2 - \overline{x} x_i \right) \right]\\
&= E\left[ \sum x_i^2 \right] - E\left[ \sum \overline{x} x_i \right]\\
&= \sum x_i^2 - \sum \overline{x} x_i\\
&= \sum x_i \left( x_i - \overline{x} \right)\\
&= S_{xx}
\end{align*}